# Idea. internal java compiler error occurs when I try to assign int to Stream#reduce operation but when Integer - not

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, java-stream, primitive, boxing

I have found following strange behaviour of streams

lets research following code:

```
int summaryAge = Person.getPersons().stream()
                .parallel()  //will return surprising result
                .reduce(0, (intermediateResult, p) -> intermediateResult + p.age,
                        (ir1, ir2) -> ir1 + ir2);
```

Idea doesn't highlight any errors but when I run application I see following compilation error:

```
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

but when I replace it using `Integer` like this:

```
Integer summaryAge = Person.getPersons().stream()
                    .parallel()  //will return surprising result
                    .reduce(0, (intermediateResult, p) -> intermediateResult + p.age,
                            (ir1, ir2) -> ir1 + ir2);
```

It works properly.

model:

```
public class Person {

    String name;

    Integer age;
    ///...

    public static Collection<Person> getPersons() {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Vasya", 12));
        persons.add(new Person("Petya", 32));
        persons.add(new Person("Serj", 10));
        persons.add(new Person("Onotole", 18));
        return persons;
   }
}
```

Does it bug of idea or compiler?

Comment: Your first snippet of code compiles fine for me (running javac 1.8.0_51 with Maven)

Comment: @Tunaki I use idea. http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/151001/b29bd185b8.jpg

Comment: looks like we use same version of jdk

Comment: If you're asking for whether this is a compiler bug (and anything that says "internal compiler error is!"), you should tell us which version of the compiler you are using....

Comment: Is it the IntelliJ compiler throwing an error or is it javac?

Comment: Hm.I installed idea and use default configuration

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that there is a problem which interestingly seems not to occur when the compiler is launched from the command line. I merged your code snippets into one file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;


public class Person {

    String name;

    Integer age;
    ///...

    Person(String n, int a) {
        name=n;
        age=a;
    }
    public static Collection<Person> getPersons() {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("Vasya", 12));
        persons.add(new Person("Petya", 32));
        persons.add(new Person("Serj", 10));
        persons.add(new Person("Onotole", 18));
        return persons;
   }

    public static void main(String... arg) {
        int summaryAge = Person.getPersons().stream()
            .parallel()  //will return surprising result
            .reduce(0, (intermediateResult, p) -> intermediateResult + p.age,
                    (ir1, ir2) -> ir1 + ir2);
    }
}
```

When compiling it with `javac` (1.8.0_60) from the command line, there are no problems. When running the same compiler from my Netbeans installation (8.0.2 patch 2), I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Types.isConvertible(Types.java:292)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.assertConvertible(Check.java:933)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkMethod(Check.java:887)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethod(Attr.java:4054)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkIdInternal(Attr.java:3826)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethodIdInternal(Attr.java:3733)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkMethodId(Attr.java:3710)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.checkId(Attr.java:3698)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3581)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1903)
…
```